# SQL Column Formulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, formula

Is it possible to add use a SELECT query for a Computed Column Specification, or a Formula?  I would like to use this query:

```
SELECT IIF( [Name] = 'Tuition'
           , CONVERT([DECIMAL](15,2),Cost * t1.SubjectUnit)
           , CONVERT([DECIMAL](15,2),Cost)
       ) as FinalCost 
FROM [HCCDB].[dbo].[SubjectOfferedFee] AS t0
        INNER JOIN HCCDB.dbo.SubjectsOffered  AS t1
            ON t1.SubjectsOfferedID = t0.SubjectsOfferedID
```

In an ALTER table statement:

```
ALTER TABLE HCCDB.dbo.SubjectOfferedFee
  ADD FinalCost AS [THE QUERY SELECT QUERY ABOVE]
```

I have tried this on the other column, by concatenating the columns by creating a new column and adding a Formula.

```
CONVERT([varchar](50),[FirstName]) 
    + ' ' + CONVERT([varchar](50),[MiddleName]) 
    + ' ' + CONVERT([varchar](4),[LastName])
```

It works, but how about adding a SELECT query?

Comment: can't use derived values elsewhere in the same field list as where that derived value is defined. you'd have to use a subselect to do the computations, then you can use the derived value as if it had always existed in the query in the containing/wrapping query.

Comment: Without testing/checking, I think if you encapsulate your query in a user-defined function, you can use the function in a computed column specification.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply create a user define function on your current context.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetSubjectCost(@id INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL 
AS 
-- Returns cost if the subject that if particular name is equal to Tuition then cost x unit.
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret DECIMAL;

SELECT @ret = IIF([Name] = 'Tuition', CONVERT([DECIMAL](15,2),Cost * t1.SubjectUnit), CONVERT([DECIMAL](15,2),Cost))
    FROM [HCCDB].[dbo].[SubjectOfferedFee] AS t0
        INNER JOIN HCCDB.dbo.SubjectsOffered  AS t1
            ON t1.SubjectsOfferedID = t0.SubjectsOfferedID
            WHERE t0.SubjectOfferedFeeID = @id
IF (@ret IS NULL) 
SET @ret = 0;
RETURN @ret;
END;
GO
```

Then you can use this function to computed column specification or

```
ALTER TABLE HCCDB.dbo.SubjectOfferedFee
ADD FinalCost AS CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), dbo.fnGetSubjectCost(CONVERT(INT, [SubjectOfferedFeeID])))
```

then solved.